# Determine a positively oriented ON-basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$ so that $e_1$ lies in the plane $M_1$ and $e_2$ in $M_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

The planes $M_1 : x −2y + 3z = 1$ and
$M_2 : 4x −y −2z = 11$ are mutually orthogonal and both of them are parallel to the
line
$L : (x, y, z) = (1, 1, 1) + t(1, 2, 1)$, $t ∈R$.
Determine a positively oriented ON-basis $e_1, e_2, e_3$, so that
$e_1$ lies in $M_1$ and $e_2$ in $M_2$. (Positive ON-system assumed.)

So I'm unsure what makes a plane contain a vector. If a vector is orthogonal to the normal of the plane equivalently parallel to the plane is it then contained in the plane? If so then the normal of each plane is contained in other one and  the direction vector of the line is orthogonal to both of these.

Anyway it would be nice with a correct answer so I can study it and compare it to how I'm thinking

Comment: It is badly/sloppily stated. Since the planes do not go through the origin,  they do not contain the vectors. They should say *parallel* to the respective planes.